# undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass when method destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I want the user who created post and admin to delete but it's throwing me an 'undefined error'. I want to know why it's throwing me an undefined method error.

Here's my code from the controller:

Before actions:

```
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :like]
  before_action :require_user, except: [:show, :index, :like]
  before_action :require_user_like, only: [:like]
  before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_or_authorship, only: :destroy
```

Destroy method:

```
  def destroy
    Recipe.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Deleted"
    redirect_to stories_path
  end

 private 

    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :summary, :description)
    end

    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    end

    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @recipe.user and !current_user.admin? 
        flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own recipes"
        redirect_to stories_path
      end
    end

    def require_user_like
      if !logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "log in to like!"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end

    def admin_or_authorship
      redirect_to stories_path unless administrator? || authorship?
    end

    def administrator?
      current_user.admin?
    end

    def authorship?
       @recipe.user == current_user
    end
```

Comment: Post your exception backtrace

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your before_filter `admin_or_authorship`, which is further calling `authorship?`, is saying `@recipe.user ...`. Here `@recipe` is not defined so is `nil` by default.

You need to call before_filter `set_recipe` for `destroy` too:

```
before_action :set_recipe, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :like, :destroy]
```

Your action will become:

```
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Deleted"
    redirect_to stories_path
  end
```